# Configure maven-release-plugin to push version changes to git repository?

Tags: git, maven, release, maven-release-plugin, maven-scm-plugin

When releasing an artifact with maven-release-plugin, the changes made to the artifact version are local and not pushed to the remote git repository.

The following is the configuration I used for the maven-release-plugin:

```
<configuration>
    <goals>pre-integration-test</goals>
    <preparationGoals>package</preparationGoals>
    <releaseProfiles>releases</releaseProfiles>
</configuration>
```

I did some research and found out I need to add the following dependency `maven-scm-plugin`, but not sure how to configure it along with the maven release plugin.

Comment: The dependency to maven-scm-plugin is not needed nor necessary cause maven-release-plugin handles that itself. Why have you changed the default configuration of maven-release-plugin?

Comment: Somehow it is needed, without it maven release does not push the changes performed on the `pom.xml` to git, as a consequence keeps releasing the snapshot version.

Comment: Which maven-release-plugin version do you use? Sounds like you are using a  very old one..please post a link to your project....

Comment: I use the version 2.5.3 of maven-release-plugin, I have documented below how I solved the problem

Comment: How does your scm part in your pom look like?

Comment: see the answer below.

Comment: I don't want to see the dependencies. The SCM part https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#SCM

Comment: Well it was configured properly from the beginning, the connection, developerConnection and tag. Without the url it still works.I have admin rights on the developerConnetion. That was not my problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by adding the following dependency to the plugin dependencies:

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-gitexe</artifactId>
       <version>1.11.2</version>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

Now maven pushes the changes made to the `pom.xml` after running `mvn release:prepare` and `mvn release:perform`

Comment: I think you meant to say "to the plugin dependencies".